# Find $E[E[X \mid Y]]$ where $X \sim \mathrm{Geo}[Y]$ and $Y \sim \mathrm{Unif}[0, \frac{n-1}{n}]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-expectation, expected-value

We have the random variable $X$ distributed geometrically with parameter $Y$ which is itself a random variable uniformly distributed over the interval $[0, \frac{n-1}{n}]$.

We want to find $E[E[X \mid Y]]$.

First, it is important to recognize that $E[X \mid Y=y] = \frac{1}{y}$ by the definition of a geometric distribution's expectation. So, this implies we can treat $E[X \mid Y=y]$ as a random variable that has expectation $\frac{1}{y}$ when $y \in [0, \frac{n-1}{n}]$

Because $E[X \mid Y]$ is itself a random variable, we can just label it as $M$: a new random variable.

The question is to find $E[M]$. I have already solved this, without much thinking and uninterestingly, by using the law of iterated expectations:

$$E[M] = E[E[X \mid Y]] = E[X] = \frac{1}{Y}$$

But, I feel like there is a more rigorous proof of this relationship. Is there a way to use the PDF of $Y$ to more deliberately solve for $E[M]$?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For clarity, I'll write $E_Y(E_X(X|Y))$ to indicate that the inner expectation is taken over $X$ and the outer over $Y$.

The inner expectation, $E_X(X|Y)$ is equal either to $\frac{1}{Y}$ or $\frac{1}{Y}-1$, depending on the particular "flavour" of the [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) you're referring to.

The outer expectation, $E_Y(\frac{1}{Y})$ or $E_Y(\frac{1}{Y}-1)$, is then infinite, as it's basically the area under the curve $z=1/y$.

Comment: This makes no sense to me at the moment. I will go over it many times until it does! Thank you.

Comment: Is there any part that's particularly troublesome?

Comment: Yes, there are a few. Can we begin with how $E[X \mid Y] = \frac{1}{Y}$ or $\frac{1}{Y} -1$? i.e. what is meant by "flavour". Thank you.

Comment: Sure.  $X\sim\textrm{Geom}(Y)$, so $E_X(X|Y)$ is the mean of $\textrm{Geom}(Y)$.  I just looked-up that mean in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) -- see info box on the right-hand side of that page.  Oh, and by "flavour" I just meant whichever of the two definitions of "Geometric" we're actually talking about here; annoyingly (not your fault!) it's ambiguous.

Comment: Ahh, I never even knew that "flavor" existed. I've always been taught it to be $\frac{1}{P}$. Let's assume we are using this version, meaning we are at the point where we want $E_Y[\frac{1}{Y}]$, why don't we just compute this by plugging in $Y$'s distribution function as a uniform random variable?

Comment: That "plugging in" is exactly what we do.  Let $m=(n-1)/n$.  Then $E(\frac{1}{Y})=\int_{y=0}^{y=m} \frac{1}{y}\frac{1}{m}\ \textrm{d}y$, which is infinite.  If you're unfamiliar with integrals, you can get a feel for why this works by considering what happens if $Y$ can take any value in $\{0,\frac{1}{1000},\frac{2}{1000},\ldots,\frac{999}{1000},1\}$: there's a small but non-zero chance in *that* case that $Y=0$, i.e. $\frac{1}{Y}=\infty$, which forces the expectation to be infinite as well.

Comment: That is perfect. That was a great explanation thanks for helping me along. So my original answer of $E[M] = E[E[X \mid Y]] = \frac{1}{y}$ is not correct! Thanks again.